# Why does this constructor throw a NoSuchMethodException with reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I've tried this code:

```
System.out.println(java.util.Scanner.class.getConstructor(System.in.getClass()));
```

but I get this error and I do not understand why:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.Scanner.<init>(java.io.BufferedInputStream)
```

even though 'new Scanner(System.in)' works

Comment: `getConstructor` expects the formal parameter type, not one of its subtypes.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis so how can I get that class from 'System.in'?

Comment: @DudmasterUltraScratcher You don't get it from `System.in`, you get it from the documentation.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, but in this context I'm writing a scripting language on top of Java and I need to find these things at runtime via reflection

Comment: You "can't". The duplicate linked lays out a strategy for looping through inheritance hierarchy and finding a `Method` (or `Constructor` in your case) that matches.

Comment: That'll help - thanks